# MathML displays square roots of fractions incorrectly

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, math-display

I had set my preferences to use MathML, but I've just realised it fails to display square root of fractions correctly. With MathML, 
$$\sqrt{\frac{n-2}{1-r^2}}$$
looks almost the same as
$$\frac{ \sqrt{n-2}}{1-r^2}$$
In particular, the square-root encloses only the numerator, which changes the interpretation of the formula

I'm using Firefox 3.6.10 under Windows XP Pro Service Pack 3. I selected MathML by right-clicking any displayed formula to display a context menu and selecting Settings => Math Renderer => MathML.

Apologies if this is a MathML problem rather than a StackExchange problem. I don't know where to raise MathML bugs though.

EDIT: Snip of screenshot as requested:
[image: wrongly displayed square-root of fraction under MathML]

Comment: I'm unable to replicate, mind posting a pic of the problem?

Comment: The square root of the entire fraction in the first expression looks fine to me (FireFox 3.6.13 on Win 7/64).  Exactly how was the screen shot generated?  What browser, what OS, which Web page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the fonts! I was able to replicate after I uninstalled [these](https://developer.mozilla.org/@api/deki/files/4719/=STIX-mozilla1.9.zip). Hence installing the fonts renders the formula correctly.

Via https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Mozilla_MathML_Project/Fonts

Comment: Many thanks Andy! I would have realised it was a font issue if it'd displayed question marks or boxes with hex numbers in, as that page appears to indicate. Displaying a reasonable-looking formula with a different meaning is more worrying.

Comment: @onestop - I can't say I understand why that is the case, and Google Chrome behaves differently than Firefox whether or not the fonts are installed.